# Gateway timeout before How to optimize

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have what I assume is a pretty simple query, which is essentially collecting our `Customer` object and counting the orders associated with that customer.  But every time I try to load more than a weeks worth of `Customer` data, I get 504 timeouts, I assume from the system taking to long to collect everything.  We use Spree as our eComm framework, which handles the `Product` & `Order`.

What am I missing that's making this collection of objects so labor intensive on our servers?  It's a good 45 seconds before our server kicks us off with the 504.

`customer.rb (model)`:

```
has_many :orders, foreign_key: :customer_id, class_name: "Spree::Order"

  def sorted_orders
    orders.sort_by(&:completed_at)
  end

  def non_sub_orders
    orders.where(purchased_via_subscription: false)
  end

  def standard_items 
    orders.joins(:products).merge(Spree::Product.where(is_default: true))
  end

  def spec_items 
    orders.joins(:products).merge(Spree::Product.where(is_default: false))
  end
```

`customers_controller.rb`:

```
@customers = Customer.joins(:orders).where(spree_orders: {purchased_via_subscription: false, completed_at: @from...@to}).uniq
```

`customers/index.html.erb (view)`:

```
<form class="filter_form col-10">
Dates: <%= text_field(:date, :from, type: 'date', value: params[:date].try(:[], :from), style: "") %>

to <%= text_field(:date, :to, type: 'date', value: params[:date].try(:[], :to), style: "") %>                   
                    
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>

<% @customers.each_with_index do |c, index| %>
<tbody id="tbodyid">
<tr>
<td><%= index + 1 %></td>
<td><a href="/customers/<%= c.email %>" style="color: black;"><%= c.email %></a></td>
<td><%= c.sorted_orders.first.completed_at.strftime("%D") %></td>
<td><%= c.sorted_orders.last.completed_at.strftime("%D") %></td>
<td><%= c.spec_items.count %></td>
<td><%= c.standard_items.count %></td>
<td><%= c.non_sub_orders.count %></td>
<td><%= number_to_currency(c.total_revenue/c.non_sub_orders.count) %></td>
<td><%= number_to_currency(c.total_revenue) %></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not only `N + 1 queries` problem but also `custom queries` (which `#includes` will not fix).

solution (maybe): create `custom associations` for custom queries and preload them.

```rb
# customer.rb
has_many :orders, foreign_key: :customer_id, class_name: "Spree::Order"

has_many :sorted_orders, -> { sort_by(&:completed_at) }, class_name: "Spree::Order"
has_many :non_sub_orders, -> { where(purchased_via_subscription: false) }, class_name: "Spree::Order"
has_many :standard_items, -> { joins(:products).merge(Spree::Product.where(is_default: true)) }, class_name: "Spree::Order"
has_many :spec_items, -> { joins(:products).merge(Spree::Product.where(is_default: false)) }, class_name: "Spree::Order"

# customers_controller.rb
@customers = Customer.joins(:orders)
.where(spree_orders: {purchased_via_subscription: false, completed_at: @from...@to})
.includes(:sorted_orders, :non_sub_orders, :standard_items, :spec_items)
.uniq
```

Comment: This is somehow making it load worse.  Now I can't even load a single days worth of customer data and it gives me a 504 timeout.

Comment: @Alex, i think some of custom queries `reference` to the `joins` so it makes the `includes` load worse, could you try includes each custom query to figure out what is bad, e.g. only `sorted_orders`.